# Insert HTML with embedded Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, erb

Is there a way that I can insert HTML tags with embedded Ruby?

I'm trying to loop over items in my database and need to put them in a bootstrap grid.

```
<% @div = "</div> <div class='row'> <div class='col-md-3'>" %>
<% @end = "</div>" %>



  <div class="row">
    <% @branches.each_with_index do |b, index| %>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="cardje transition">
          <h2 class="transition"><%= b.description %></p>

          <div class="cta-container transition"><a href="#" class="cta">Import branch</a></div>
          <div class="cardje_circle transition"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <% if index+1%4 == 0 %>
        <%= @div.html_safe %>
    <% end %>
    <% if index+1 == @branches.count %>
        <% @end.html_safe %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

There must be a simpler way but I need this page to be done by tomorrow morning and I've been working way too long.

When I check the source code it's running only the loop and never implementing anything (so everything is on one row and overlapping).

Comment: The data i'm inserting is just a name and description.
Currently it looks like this but its all on one row and overlapping,
I need it to create a new row each 4 elements.
http://gyazo.com/142768d56e3e6ac44c38acec6716057c
Mouseover makes it slide open and show the Import branch button.

Comment: A couple of minor comments: you are using instance variables in your view when you don't have to (or shouldn't). That is, `@div` and `@end` in particular. Just use local variable names for those, unless you need to make them persistent over the existence of the class instance. And you're missing an `=`: `<% @end.html_safe %>` should be `<%= @end.html_safe %>`.

Comment: I see some additional issues. You have a dangling `<h2>` (no closing `</h2>` in your code sample). It also looks like the first time you use `<%= @div.html_safe %>` it's going to close off the `<div` that comes before your `each_with_index_do` loop, so that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Also missing an closing tag for your div with the class "row".